# why gamekit auto-match always timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit

I'm a newbie iOS developer, currently working on a board game. I would like to integrate UIGameKit, but I'm having trouble. It seems to always fail to auto-match, and invite friends...

I did check the build bundle id, and i've enabled gc in itunes connect, but still no luck. When I click "play now" on the device or simulator, nothing happens until it times out. When I click "invite friend", it also will fail with the following error message:

```
ERROR: {
    GKServerStatusCode = 5008;
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5008 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. status = 5008, missing required key: self-push-token\" UserInfo=0xae53360 {GKServerStatusCode=5008, NSLocalizedFailureReason=status = 5008, missing required key: self-push-token}";
```

I don't understand what gamekit required key am I missing? What is the self-push-token the error message is asking for?

(**Editors Remark:** Don't think below code is relevant, will leave here anyways)

```
GKMatchRequest* request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;

GKMatchmakerViewController* hostVC = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
if (hostVC != nil)
{
    hostVC.matchmakerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:hostVC];
}
```

Can any help? I tried to find some good samples to build a simple gamekit auto-match app but didn't have any luck, does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: the code used to show up the GC findmatch view, why not relevant?

Comment: Could you resolve this issue? Could you tell us what the problem was? I'm having the same problem!

Comment: The simulator cannot receive push notifications (needed for Game Center invites) so it should not be surprising that the simulator gives back this kind of error ("missing required key: self-push-token"), but the device should not do something like this. 

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the Push Notification Certificate we are using.

Comment: I have the same error, except it's 
    "status = 5008, missing required header key: x-gk-bundle-version"